# My Model input_shape don't match my X's input_shape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am developing an image denoiser with python for my scientific initiation scholarship, however, when I went to carry out the first test training, I came across some errors.

Basically I need to train a grayscale array [27, 265036] with a desired output [1, 265036]
using a single layer model

** for every 27 inputs i have a single desired output

My model:

[image: Model]

I tried to run the training, but on the first attempt the following error occurred:
[image: Erro1]

I tried to reshape the x and y, but the following occurred:
[image: erro2]

I changed the model inputs, from x and y, created a matrix [27, 265036] repeated the values ​​of y so there was no difference in the amount of samples, but nothing worked

my advisor and I have been stuck on these errors for two weeks and I really want to be able to train this network

Here is the code:

```
modelo = Sequential()

modelo.add(keras.Input(shape=[27, 265036], name = 'input1'))

modelo.add(Dense(15, activation="sigmoid", name = 'input2'))

modelo.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")

modelo.build()

print(modelo.summary())


plot_model(modelo, to_file = 'D:\Bolsa.png', show_shapes=True, dpi=300)
```

```
history = modelo.fit(X_train, SaidaDesejada, epochs=1, batch_size=1)
```

Comment: Please don't take screenshots of your code and errors. Instead you should include them in your question as text. That way it is easier for people to work with it. [ask]

Answer (score -1):

```
modelo.add(keras.Input(shape=X_train[1].shape, name = 'input1'))
```

i am dumb.

Comment: Please explain how exactly did that fix your problem for the future people possibly coming here with similar problem instead of senseless self-blame